# How can I update a progress bar's progress (using 0-100 integers) with a long and int data types?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I'm working on a very basic Android app, and I need to update a progress bar in correspondence to the loops traversal to find if an entered number is prime.  The entered number must be of long data type.  The plan was to traverse a loop from i = 2 to sqrt(number), and divide the entered number by i each iteration.  If i divides the number, then the loop ends, and we decide it is NOT a prime.

Otherwise, the loop keeps going, meanwhile updating the progress.  Here is a snippet of the pertinent code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Long... params) {
String message;
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);

long lim = (long)Math.sqrt(params[0]);

for (int i = 2; i <= lim; i++) {
        if (params[0] % i == 0) {
    message = params[0] + " is not prime!";
    int myProgressFinal = 100;
        publishProgress(myProgressFinal);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
    return null;
        }
        else {              
            int myProgress = i/lim * 100;
            publishProgress(myProgress);

            if (isCancelled())
                return null;
        }
    }

message = params[0] + " is prime!";
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
startActivity(intent);
return null;
}

}
```

My problem spot is the else statement:

```
else {              
    int myProgress = i/lim * 100;
    publishProgress(myProgress);
```

I have an integer i for the loop, showing my progression through the loop, and to find the percentage that I've advanced, I would have to divide by the max amount of the loop (lim = sqrt(number)) and then multiply by 100 to get the proper percentage.  However, I can't do this b/c myProgress is an integer, but lim is a long, and cannot be changed to int.  Even if I make lim an int, I still have integer division giving me a wrong value (0 * 100).  It won't let me typecast one of them to double b/c myProgress has to be int in order to be passed through publishProgress().  Any suggestions?

Comment: I think I figured it out.  Does this make sense?  (I can't test it b/c I'm not done with the asynctask code).  Anyways, I type cast the entire formula:  int myProgress = (int)(i/lim * 100);  Will that keep me from getting a zero value every time?  Thanks for your time and insight.

Comment: The easy solution is `int myProgress = (i*100)/lim;`

Comment: I've had similar issues programing for arduinoTry multiplying iby 100 first then divide by lim eg `myProgress = (i*100)/lim;'

Comment: I tested your theories @beaker and pvyParts, but I still cannot do this because I am trying to turn a long into an int, which is not possible.

Comment: Based on the comment from @fragorl I decided to actually go and try it :) This code works: `int myProgress = (int)(((long)i*100)/lim);` when i is declared as int, but if i is declared as a long (as it probably should be) the code in my original comment works by casting it as an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, if 'i' is going to range all the way up to lim, 'i' will need to be a long as well. Otherwise, once 'i' hits Integer.MAX_VALUE, the next iteration is going to cause overflow.

I believe you want to declare i as a long, and in your else statement do

"int myProgress = (int)((((double)i)/lim) * 100)"

Comment: I tried commenting on pvyParts's solution, but my rep won't allow me to. Even if you've declared i as a long, multiplying it by 100 first will potentially cause overflow as well. Consider the case where 'lim' and 'i' are just a little less than Long.MAX_VALUE. Multiplying 'i' by 100 will send it well over the MAX_VALUE limit.  
  
I think you need to do something like "int myProgress = (int)((((double)i)/lim) * 100)"

Comment: But since lim is the square root of (at most) Long.MAX_VALUE, multiplying it by 100 will never overflow.